# What was the job you were most proud of doing in 2011?

Tags: 2011, project

What project did you complete in 2011 that you were most proud of and really did a smoking job on?

Answer (score 8):

I can't judge whether I did a smokin' job on it or not, but I was really proud of the work we did on Captain America: The First Avenger. A very tall order in an extremely short amount of time. Lots of talented people put their 110% into it and I think it shows.

Comment: And it sounded awesome! Well done :-)

Comment: Dear Jay, the sound designer of that movie had good things to say about you at a sound design seminar I attended with him. I thought you did a great job!

Comment: Awesome movie, awesome sounds!

Comment: @Andrew, @Ville, @Utopia, thank you very much for the kind words! As said before, it was a true team effort - and I was really pleased to be a part of it.

Answer (score 4):

Amazing and inspiring question!

Completed my first commissioned work for a dance company this year. Worked more than a few 18 hour days towards the end of the production for the love of wanting to get it perfect and absolutely right. I feel more defined as an artist as a result.

Comment: @dmengi Awesome!!! Great job and congrats!

Answer (score 3):

hmmm good question, i somehow wrapped my first feature documentary. definitely a different animal from narrative work... Happy New Year!

Comment: Cool! Good luck in the New Year!! What is the name of said documentary?

Comment: Thanks and to you as well! It's called "Ruffo" about the surfer of the same name. Not sure of the release date yet...

Answer (score 3):

These all sound like really cool projects, well done to all :)

For me, 2011 was the year I started my career as a sound designer for games, so the project I'm most proud of? My first AAA shipped game: "LEGO: Harry Potter Years 5-7"

I'm proud of it, but already I'm looking at some of my work in it and seeing places it could be improved. That's a good thing though right? :)

Comment: This happens to me a lot. On reflection we always find things to improve. But keep in mind 'perfection' is incredibly difficult to define when speaking of aesthetics or creativity. It's a very personal, individualized thing. 

Congratulations on the achievement. 

Comment: Great! What exactly did you do on the game? Or was it everything?

Comment: @Colin True, always about knowing when to leave it. And thank you!
@Utopia I came in quite late, so didn't do any in-game stuff but the majority of the Year 6 and Year 7 cutscenes were my work :)

Answer (score 3):

It is telling how professional and humble the users of this forum are - even in a thread specifically prompting everyone to share their best work from an entire year, most don't mention the specific title of their project and all frame their pride within statements of "hearing mistakes" "tweeking more" "learning curves" etc.  This is exactly why I am so appreciative of the users who post here.  Even the Captain America post by Jay spends most of the word count of the team, says "we" instead of I, and still prefaces his pride statement with "I can't judge whether I did a smokin' job on it or not."  Within this environment refined skill and hard work naturally are elevated.

Comment: This is the exact reason why I love SSD. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I finished up sound post on my first feature this year. We had an excellent dialogue editor/ADR recordist, who i was very thankful to have, because i pretty much did the rest. A year of late nights and weekends, trial and error, guerilla foley in vo booths/the producer's basement, and by the time we were done, i still felt like i had 1000 more things i wanted to tweak.

I watched it through the other day when i was recording out DME stems, and i'm pretty satisfied with it.

Comment: Cool! What is the name of the film? I'd like to see it :)

Answer (score 2):

The project I am most proud of during 2011 was a documentary about a French comedian. I was the sound recordist throughout the shoot that took place during a week-long festival, then I oversaw the sound post-production back in Paris.

Not only was it for a high-profile client, which obviously brings with it a lot of stress, but it was also the first time I have been involved from start to finish (location to post). It turned out to be a big learning curve.

Answer (score 2):

Supervising my first show from scratch (pilot through the 1st season) Extremely proud and thankful for the crew I get to work with. From runners, assistants, editors, mixers to the producers.

Were there things I thought could have been better? Of course. But knowing the turn around time we had and the caliber of the work put in makes me feel proud,thankful and extremely blessed that I get to do what I do for a living. 2011 was a good year personally and professionally for me. I look forward to the things I'll learn and people I'll meet and work with in 2012.

I hope everyone here has a good year in and out of sound in 2012. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

Most proud of our work on an online promo for some gaming headphones created by Tritton for Xbox360. Really exciting cinematic sound.

Looking forward to 2012!

Answer (score 1):

in 2011 I did a successful [kickstarter project](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/675954423/the-uptown-trolley-sound-library), helped to launch [echo | collective](http://www.echocollectivefx.com/), and supervised sound on a great little short called "[crescendo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1805526/)", which I think is the best work I've personally pulled off to date.